# In Android Bad Parcelable Exception causing the more crashes

Tags: android

In App while calling the OnResume method crashes are happening due to Bad Parcelable Exception but We are not sending any Parcelable value. While reading the Parcelable getting this error .It is not able to reproduce also.

```
"Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3864)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4006)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:111)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2462)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:240)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:351)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8377)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1013)
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException:
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4690)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4349)
  at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal (Parcel.java:5391)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4645)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4341)
  at android.os.Parcel.-$$Nest$mreadValue
  at android.os.Parcel$LazyValue.apply (Parcel.java:4439)
  at android.os.Parcel$LazyValue.apply (Parcel.java:4398)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValueAt (BaseBundle.java:394)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue (BaseBundle.java:374)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue (BaseBundle.java:357)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue (BaseBundle.java:350)
  at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray (Bundle.java:1088)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.restoreState (FragmentStateManager.java:408)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveStateInternal (FragmentManager.java:2512)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState (Fragment.java:1989)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate (Fragment.java:1965)
  at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate (NavHostFragment.kt:169)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:3090)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create (FragmentStateManager.java:475)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:257)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:113)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1433)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:2977)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate (FragmentManager.java:2884)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate (FragmentController.java:252)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:220)
  at com.disha.quickride.androidapp.FragmentActivity.onCreate (MyActivity.java:65)
  at com.disha.quickride.androidapp.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:198)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8397)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8370)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1403)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3837)
```